# Embed matplotlib graph image into HTML code

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I am trying to embedded a matplotlib graph image into a html code.
But i am unable to find how to do it. Below is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values = np.array([2,5,3,6,4,7,1])   
idx = np.array(list('abcdefg')) 
clrs = ['grey' if (x < max(values)) else 'red' for x in values ]
plt.bar(idx, values, color=clrs, width=0.4)
plt.show()

htmlbody=
        "<p><br>Please find the below graph,</br></p>
             ......want to embed the above plot graph image here.... 
                     <p><br>Thanks,</br></p>"
```

Please help me how i can embed the plot image into the above html code.

Comment: What is happening, not happening?  Is there an error? What do you mean json body?  if the mail body should be json, it is not appropriately formatted json.  Json starts and end with {} for example.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Comment: Hi @ivan7707 thank your for your comment, i updated my request. Please help me to understand how i can embed the plot graph image in html. Please i need some help Thanks.

Comment: Where is the rest of the code?  Why is there that msgbody variable? you can save the figure then reference it <img src='my_plot.png'/>, or encode as base64, then include in img tag.

Comment: Hi @ivan7707 could you please help me any sample code snippet for the steps. It will be very helpful.

Comment: There are I am sure many examples on Stack Overflow that you can find. Good luck